# How to kill python interpreter with long running C/C++ code executed in the backend?

Tags: python, c++, c

In the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#execution-of-python-signal-handlers), it seems like signal sent from python side could not kill long-running C/C++ process:

> A long-running calculation implemented purely in C (such as regular expression matching on a large body of text) may run uninterrupted for an arbitrary amount of time, regardless of any signals received. The Python signal handlers will be called when the calculation finishes.

Is there a workaround for this? Could I implement something in C/C++ side(i.e, a callback function?) to capture keyboard interruption?

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround [here](http://snakesthatbite.blogspot.com/2010/09/cpython-threading-interrupting.html), it seems like making the long running CPython program a daemon thread is one way to handle it.